# MemoryError cross_val_score Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am newbie in programming and machine learning. I am doing an assignment on KNN and amazon fine food reviews but getting this error.

My code:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

Y = data['Score'].values
X_with_stop= data['Text_with_stop'].values
X_no_stop = data['New_Text'].values

X_with_stop_train, X_with_stop_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X_with_stop, Y, test_size=0.33, shuffle=False)

print(X_with_stop_train.shape, y_train.shape,y_test.shape)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
bow_X_train_brute = vectorizer.fit_transform(X_with_stop_train)
bow_X_test_brute = vectorizer.transform(X_with_stop_test)

from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

neighbors = list(range(3,99,2))

cv_scores = []

for k in neighbors:
    knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k,algorithm='brute')
    scores = cross_val_score(knn, bow_X_train_brute, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
    cv_scores.append(scores.mean())

MSE = [1 - x for x in cv_scores]

# determining best k
optimal_k = neighbors[MSE.index(min(MSE))]
print ("The optimal number of neighbors is %d" % optimal_k)

# plot misclassification error vs k
plt.plot(neighbors, MSE)
plt.xlabel('Number of Neighbors K')
plt.ylabel('Misclassification Error')
plt.title("Plot for K vs Error for Brute force algorithm")
plt.show()
```

The output:

```
(413629,) (413629,) (203729,)
```

The error i am getting is as below:

```
MemoryError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f1ce8e46a2a3> in <module>()
 43 for k in neighbors:
 44     knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=k,algorithm='brute')
---> 45     scores = cross_val_score(knn, bow_X_train_brute, y_train, cv=10, scoring='accuracy')
46     cv_scores.append(scores.mean())
47 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_val_score(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch)
340                                 n_jobs=n_jobs, verbose=verbose,
341                                 fit_params=fit_params,
--> 342                                 pre_dispatch=pre_dispatch)
343     return cv_results['test_score']
344 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in cross_validate(estimator, X, y, groups, scoring, cv, n_jobs, verbose, fit_params, pre_dispatch, return_train_score)
204             fit_params, return_train_score=return_train_score,
205             return_times=True)
--> 206         for train, test in cv.split(X, y, groups))
207 
208     if return_train_score:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self, iterable)
777             # was dispatched. In particular this covers the edge
    778             # case of Parallel used with an exhausted iterator.
--> 779             while self.dispatch_one_batch(iterator):
780                 self._iterating = True
781             else:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in dispatch_one_batch(self, iterator)
623                 return False
624             else:
--> 625                 self._dispatch(tasks)
626                 return True
627 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in _dispatch(self, batch)
586         dispatch_timestamp = time.time()
587         cb = BatchCompletionCallBack(dispatch_timestamp, len(batch), self)
--> 588         job = self._backend.apply_async(batch, callback=cb)
589         self._jobs.append(job)
    590 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in apply_async(self, func, callback)
    109     def apply_async(self, func, callback=None):
    110         """Schedule a func to be run"""
--> 111         result = ImmediateResult(func)
    112         if callback:
    113             callback(result)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\_parallel_backends.py in __init__(self, batch)
    330         # Don't delay the application, to avoid keeping the input
    331         # arguments in memory
--> 332         self.results = batch()
    333 
    334     def get(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in __call__(self)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\externals\joblib\parallel.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    129 
    130     def __call__(self):
--> 131         return [func(*args, **kwargs) for func, args, kwargs in self.items]
    132 
    133     def __len__(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _fit_and_score(estimator, X, y, scorer, train, test, verbose, parameters, fit_params, return_train_score, return_parameters, return_n_test_samples, return_times, error_score)
    486         fit_time = time.time() - start_time
    487         # _score will return dict if is_multimetric is True
--> 488         test_scores = _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    489         score_time = time.time() - start_time - fit_time
    490         if return_train_score:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer, is_multimetric)
    521     """
    522     if is_multimetric:
--> 523         return _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorer)
    524     else:
    525         if y_test is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection\_validation.py in _multimetric_score(estimator, X_test, y_test, scorers)
    551             score = scorer(estimator, X_test)
    552         else:
--> 553             score = scorer(estimator, X_test, y_test)
    554 
    555         if hasattr(score, 'item'):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\scorer.py in __call__(self, estimator, X, y_true, sample_weight)
     99         super(_PredictScorer, self).__call__(estimator, X, y_true,
    100                                              sample_weight=sample_weight)
--> 101         y_pred = estimator.predict(X)
    102         if sample_weight is not None:
    103             return self._sign * self._score_func(y_true, y_pred,

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\classification.py in predict(self, X)
    143         X = check_array(X, accept_sparse='csr')
    144 
--> 145         neigh_dist, neigh_ind = self.kneighbors(X)
    146 
    147         classes_ = self.classes_

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\neighbors\base.py in kneighbors(self, X, n_neighbors, return_distance)
    355             if self.effective_metric_ == 'euclidean':
    356                 dist = pairwise_distances(X, self._fit_X, 'euclidean',
--> 357                                           n_jobs=n_jobs, squared=True)
    358             else:
    359                 dist = pairwise_distances(

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in pairwise_distances(X, Y, metric, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1245         func = partial(distance.cdist, metric=metric, **kwds)
   1246 
-> 1247     return _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1248 
   1249 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in _parallel_pairwise(X, Y, func, n_jobs, **kwds)
   1088     if n_jobs == 1:
   1089         # Special case to avoid picklability checks in delayed
-> 1090         return func(X, Y, **kwds)
   1091 
   1092     # TODO: in some cases, backend='threading' may be appropriate

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\pairwise.py in euclidean_distances(X, Y, Y_norm_squared, squared, X_norm_squared)
    244         YY = row_norms(Y, squared=True)[np.newaxis, :]
    245 
--> 246     distances = safe_sparse_dot(X, Y.T, dense_output=True)
    247     distances *= -2
    248     distances += XX

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    133     """
    134     if issparse(a) or issparse(b):
--> 135         ret = a * b
    136         if dense_output and hasattr(ret, "toarray"):
    137             ret = ret.toarray()

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\base.py in __mul__(self, other)
    477             if self.shape[1] != other.shape[0]:
    478                 raise ValueError('dimension mismatch')
--> 479             return self._mul_sparse_matrix(other)
    480 
    481         # If it's a list or whatever, treat it like a matrix

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\compressed.py in _mul_sparse_matrix(self, other)
    500                                     maxval=nnz)
    501         indptr = np.asarray(indptr, dtype=idx_dtype)
--> 502         indices = np.empty(nnz, dtype=idx_dtype)
    503         data = np.empty(nnz, dtype=upcast(self.dtype, other.dtype))
    504
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `MemoryError` usually means that you ran out of RAM. And seeing the size of your dataset, I think it might be a plausible explanation.

To be sure, just look at your RAM usage while executing your code.

Comment: yup that was the issue i reduced the datasize and yes it worked.

Comment: If that was the issue, feel free to accept the answer !

Comment: Hello Pierre-Nicolas Piquin,  I am new to stackoverflow how do i mark answer useful? I see there is up and down arrow i tried clicking "up" arrow it says "thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score"

Comment: You just have to click on the check mark below the arrows